# $\exists g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following:

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be differential at $x = 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that there exists a continuous function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ at $x = 0$ such that $f(x) = xg(x), \forall x \in \Bbb R$.

What I did was the following:

Let $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = xg(x) ,\forall x \in \Bbb R$. Then, because $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(0) - f(x)}{-x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-xg(x)}{-x} = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$$

Because $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(0) - f(x)}{-x}$ exists then $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ also exists.

So, I proved that $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists but this is not enough conlcude that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$ because I still need to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = g(0)$ but I'm not being able to do so. How can I prove this?

---

Edit:

I think I figured it out:

$f(x) = xg(x)$ so $g$ must be differentiable at $0$, Because if it's not then $f$, would be the product of a $x$ with a non-differentiable function and therefore would not be differentiable.

$f'(0) = g(0) + 0 \cdot g'(0) = g(0)$

But $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(0) - f(x)}{-x} = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$.

So we conclude that: $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = g(0)$

Is this correct?

Comment: You must *define* $g(0)$ to be the limit.

Comment: Can I simply define it that way? Or do I need to show that that is the case? @saulspatz

Comment: You are producing a function $g$.  When $x=0$, $g(x)=\frac {f(x)}x$.  When $x=0$, you need to give the definition.

Comment: @saulspatz check edit please

Comment: Your edit is not quite correct. The constant function 1 is differentiable while it is the product of $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ while $\frac{1}{x}$ is not differentiable at $0$ (it's not even defined there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(x)$ such that $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ if $x \neq 0$. And $g(0) = f'(0)$. Note that $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0)$ so $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$, and continuous elsewhere as $f(x)$ and $x$ are continuous. And $0g(0) = 0 = f(0)$ and everywhere else clearly $xg(x) = f(x)$.